# How to change the Selected tab Color in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

This is my Tabs CSS code. The tab color should change when I click on the tab.

```
/* #tab1 */
    .custom #tabbuttons .tab1 a     { background: #F6F6F6; color: #1C94C4; } /* override UI Theme */
    .custom #tabbuttons .tab1   {background:#006699}
    .custom #tabbuttons .tab1  a:hover{background: #FDF5CE;color:#FF0000}


    .custom #tabpanels #tab1,
    .custom #tab1 .ui-layout-resizer-sliding ,
    .custom #tab1 .ui-layout-west ,     /* sidebar panes too - for when 'sliding' */
    .custom #tab1 .ui-layout-east   { background: #4794D8; } 
    .custom #tab1 .ui-layout-resizer-closed { border: 1px solid #4cbf52; }
    .custom #tab1 .toolbar ,
    .custom #tab1 .ui-widget-header { background: #CEE3F6; border: 0; }
    .custom #tab1 .ui-widget-footer { background: #CEE3F6; border: 0; }
    /*
    .custom #tab1 > .ui-layout-center ,
    .custom #tab1 .ui-layout-pane .ui-layout-pane { border: 2px solid #4cbf52; }
    .custom #tab1 .ui-widget-content    { border: 1px solid #16b81e; }
    */

    /* #tab2  */
    .custom #tabbuttons .tab2 a     { background: #F6F6F6; color: #1C94C4; } /* override UI Theme */
    .custom #tabbuttons .tab2  a:hover{background: #FDF5CE;color:#FF0000}



    .custom #tabpanels #tab2,
    .custom #tab2 .ui-layout-resizer-sliding ,
    .custom #tab2 .ui-layout-west ,     /* sidebar panes too - for when 'sliding' */
    .custom #tab2 .ui-layout-east   { background: #4794D8; } 
    .custom #tab2 .ui-layout-resizer-closed { border: 1px solid #4cbf52; }
    .custom #tab2 .toolbar ,
    .custom #tab2 .ui-widget-header { background: #CEE3F6; border: 0; } 
    .custom #tab2 .ui-widget-footer { background: #CEE3F6; border: 0; } 
    /*
    .custom #tab2 > .ui-layout-center ,
    .custom #tab2 .ui-layout-pane .ui-layout-pane { border: 2px solid #4cbf52; }
    .custom #tab2 .ui-widget-content    { border: 1px solid #16b81e; }
    */
```

I have tried following codes to change color of when it selected...

```
  .custom #tabbuttons .tab1  a:selected{background: #FDF5CE;color:#FF0000}
```

or

```
.custom #tabbuttons .tab1  a:active{background: #FDF5CE;color:#FF0000}
```

or

```
.custom #tabbuttons .tab1  a:clicked{background: #FDF5CE;color:#FF0000}
```

But no one working for me.....

Also tab coding in Body are below....

```
<UL id="tabbuttons" class="hidden">
        <LI class="tab1"><A href="#tab1">Track Location</A></LI>
        <LI class="tab2"><A href="#tab2">Track Route</A></LI>
    </UL>
```

What is the problem here...How to change color of the tab...Please help me......

Comment: you have to keep your questions concise and to-the-point.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use [CSS pseudoclasses](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements) in your rules to handle jQuery UI widget state, jQuery UI adds/removes classes to reflect that.

The selected tab gets the `ui-tabs-selected` class. You can have a look at the classes and element structure of the jQuery Tabs widget in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#theming). Your CSS should look like this:

```
.custom #tabbuttons .tab1 a.ui-tabs-selected { background:#FDF5CE; color:#FF0000; }
```

The above assumes that you have an ancestor element with the class `custom`, which you forgot to include in your markup.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the use of pseudo selectors ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements ).

You will need to apply a class that makes your `<li>` selected trough javascript or andy other way. Something like:

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li class="selected"><a href="#">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#">First</a></li>
</ul>

.navigation li {background:red;}
.navigation li.selected {background:blue;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response...

I have added code like this,


    .custom #tabbuttons .tab2 li.selected { background-color:#006699; color:#FF0000; }

only Foreground color(tab name) changed when select..but background not changed....what i do...please help me...

Comment: Your <li> needs to be a block or inline-block element in order for some properties to work. Set display:inline-block or display:block - depends how you want it to behave.